# How to properly deal with .env files in docker

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a node app using `dotenv` to keep track of env variables. Its using the `.env` file in the root folder to get the variables in runtime. The problem is when i'm using docker to build a node image the below line copies the `.env` file for the build as well

```
FROM node:latest

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8000
```

If i build  & pull the image from dockerhub. The file already contains the `.env` file i used in development. Ideally , i would like to specify a different `.env` file for production. (perhaps manually creating a new .env file in the production server)

i tried specifying the `.env` file in dockerignore . but line `COPY . /usr/src/app` still seems to copy the env file as well.

I do not need to use `dotenv` as such. I tried specifying it like the below

```
version: '2'

services:
  node:
    container_name: node
    build: .
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    command: npm start
```

so i really dont need to specify a .env folder in the build. But this doesnt work as well.

How do i stop the `COPY` command from copying the `.env` file?

Answer (score 13):

There's a file for that!

> Before the docker CLI sends the context to the docker daemon, it looks for a file named [.dockerignore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) in the root directory of the context. If this file exists, the CLI modifies the context to exclude files and directories that match patterns in it. This helps to avoid unnecessarily sending large or sensitive files and directories to the daemon and potentially adding them to images using ADD or COPY.

In your case, you'll just need to `echo .env >> .dockerignore` while in the same directory as your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 4):

create a [`.dockerignore`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) file in the same directory as `.env` and `Dockerfile` then add `.env` file to `.dockerignore` file. now Docker will not include `.env` file while building the image.

```
#.dockerignore 
.env
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not simply add the following?:

```
RUN rm /usr/src/app/.env
COPY dockerenv /usr/src/app/.env
```

(Also if you're worried about .env data leaking out, be aware that the old .env file is possibly visible in the file system layers. You can squash the filesystem to get rid of this).

Comment: wouldnt this mean that i would still have a dockerenv file pushed to the image ?  It looks like this is actually a bug though - https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1607